# How to find error in script running in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This is my JSP Page , where i am using the below JS Files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/html/js/graph/finance.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/html/js/graph/excanvas.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/graph/canvastext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/graph/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/graph/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/graph/flotr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/graph/HumbleFinanceReal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html/js/graph/canvas2image.js"></script>
```

The Page works fine under Mozilla , but when i run the same page under IE , it shows

A Runtime Error has Occured
Line 629

The JSP is of only 10 Lines of code .

Hw can i know where is the Error in IE ??

Comment: the error is in one of the Javascritps. The JSPs generate HTML on your server, it's the same for every browser. Which IE version are you using? Do you get an error message?

Comment: f12 for developer tools, depending on your ie version you might need to first download them, but ie8+ has them included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [F12 developers tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507%28VS.85%29.aspx) (just press F12)?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on page and select `view source`, then you will be able to see 629th line.
The line number displayed in error considers all included js and dynamically 
generated code so it's showing error on line 625 though your jsp is of 10 line only.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the IE Developer Tools (F12). This might give some more information. You could also try to remove all your JS scripts and add one at a time to see what triggers the error.